# Array of struct type,C error

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

So, I have this struct:

```
typedef struct {
    int day;
    int amount;
    char type[4],desc[20];
 }transaction;
```

And this function to populate a vector of type *transaction* ,declared in main:

```
void transact(transaction t[],int &n)
 {
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        t[i].day=GetNumber("Give the day:");
        t[i].amount=GetNumber("Give the amount of money:");
        t[i].type=GetNumber("Give the transaction type:");
        t[i].desc=GetNumber("Give the descripition:");
    }
 }
```

The error I get at the header of the function `transact()`:

> `Multiple markers at this line`
>   `- Syntax error`
>   `- expected ';', ',' or ')' before '&' token`

Comment: After you fixed the attempt to use a reference parameter, you'll run into the problem that arrays are not assignable in `t[i].type = GetNumber("...")` and `t[i].desc = ...`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ has references such as `int &n`; C does not.

Remove the `&`.

You're then going to have problems with assigning numbers to `t[i].type` and `t[i].desc`.  They're strings, and you can't assign strings like that, and you should probably be using something like `void GetString(const char *prompt, char *buffer, size_t buflen);` to do the read and assignment:

```
GetString("Give the transaction type:", t[i].type, sizeof(t[i].type));
```

Answer (score 6):

You are attempting to declare the `n` parameter as a reference (`int &n`). But references are a C++ feature and do not exist in C.

Since the function doesn't modify the value of `n`, just make it a normal parameter:

```
void transact(transaction t[],int n)
```

You also have errors later where you are attempting to assign an array:

```
t[i].type=GetNumber("Give the transaction type:");
t[i].desc=GetNumber("Give the descripition:");
```

Since `GetNumber` probably returns a number, it isn't clear what you are trying to do there.